# How to log the real user time?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am logging which users login to the app and times. I see the time is based on the app server which is this case Azure, so it's not the real time. I was interested to show the real times they login. It seems the app server is the default, how to make this time more legitimate?

```
var loginAudit = new LogInAudit();
loginAudit.CLIENT_IP = FDB.Utils.GetClientIP();
loginAudit.LOGIN_TIME = DateTime.Now;
loginAudit.LOGIN_USER_ID = objUser.LoginID;
loginAudit.LOGOUT_TIME = null;
loginAudit.TYPE = "IN";
loginAudit.USER_ID = objUser.UserID;

db.Entry(loginAudit).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: When you say "real" time, do you mean the time in the user's current time zone?

Comment: yes means users time.

Comment: Maybe this [SO answer could help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript).

Comment: If you go with @.paulwesterberg's answer to the question @pasty linked, you should consider using Noda Time on the server, since .net and windows use different naming conventions for timezones compared to that script (which matches the names in the [tz database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing dates relative to a clients particular timezone is generally considered a display problem, whenever you are dealing with storing dates/times it's almost always recommended that you record them as UTC. At the moment, you are recording the servers *local* time against the audit record which means absolutely nothing with regards to your clients.

What you want to do is record the current UTC time in the DB record

```
loginAudit.LOGIN_TIME = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Then when displaying, convert it back to local time.

In order to do this you need to be *culture aware*, in other words, you need to know which timezone the client is on in order to translate from UTC back to local. For example, if I were a client, I would be working in `GMT Standard Time` time, so in order for me to see the audit time relative to me you would need to do

```
var gmt = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
var localTime = tzi.ConvertTimeFromUtc(loginAudit.LOGIN_TIME, gmt);
```

In terms of how to get this information from the client, there are various ways of doing this like simply letting the user select from list of available TZ (reliable but intrusive) to using a [3rd party service](http://worldtime.io/api/ip) to lookup the information based on their IP (not as reliable but better UX for the user) - I'll leave you to investigate and decide which is best for your app.

Alternatively, if you prefer to not deal with timezones and just work with dates you could just store the offset along with the UTC time which would give you the local time once calculated - see [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx).

Comment: You didn't explain how you would get the actual time zone from the client.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was hesitant to go down that road because there are too many options, however, for completeness I have added a little snippet on ways of capturing this information.

Answer (score 1):

If all of your users are in one time zone,what I have done in the past was change the time on the server to be the correct time :-)  It worked out well.

If your users span multiple time zones, you need to capture the time zone the user belongs to, and store your dates in UTC time.  UTC time is universal time, which you convert to local time through the time zone.  This is how it is typically handled.

Comment: How does one capture the time zone that the user belongs to?

Comment: @RobertHarvey For proper clients it's easy. For web applications the only way I can think of is sampling the conversion function at enough points to uniquely determine a time-zone.